# Pinging different subnet using static route

Tags: networking, routes, ping, subnet

I have two routers.

1. Provided by Internet Service Provider (192.168.1.1)
2. Asus AC-3200 (192.168.2.1)

WAN IP assigned to the router is **192.168.1.19**

A LAN wire coming from Router # 1 is connected to WAN port of Router # 2. Now I have to two different subnets, and I am unable to access computers connected to Router #1 (or the router itself) from Router #2 and vice versa.

After doing some research I found out that I need to setup static route for this. I tried following route but didn't work

```
Network/Host IP: 192.168.1.0
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
Metric: 1
Interface: LAN
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: why not put them both in the same subnet and connect the wire on the Router#2 to its LAN port?

Comment: Well unfortunately I wish I could do that. When I do that the Asus RT-3200 says that it is unable to find any internet connection resulting it unable to do anything.

Comment: did you change the gateway of the Asus to be router#1?

Comment: Yes I changed the gateway in LAN->DHCP Server of Asus to 192.168.1.1

Comment: You haven't changed the subnet of the Asus router. The Asus router needs to have an IP address in the same subnet as router#1 (`e.g. router#1=192.168.1.1 - router#2=192.168.1.2`). Make sure you only have 1 router that's handing out DHCP (either router#1 or router#2) and it needs to be in the `192.168.1.0/24` range as well (e.g. `.50 - .100`)

Comment: According to this router both can't be in same subnet. When I try to change it to 192.168.1.2 it says "WAN & LAN should have different IP Addresses & subnet" as a result of which I am unable to do like you suggested

Comment: did you also switch the cable in router#2 from the WAN port to the LAN port? You might need to edit the IP configuration for the WAN port.

Comment: Yes I tried switching from WAN to LAN port for Router # 2. When I do that it allows me to be on same subnet. But for some odd reason Router # 2 says it is unable to access internet even though I can browse. Because of Router's this behavior it is unable to perform any of the speciality tasks for which I bought it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102722/discussion-between-customx-and-saad-bashir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to setup your ASUS as a sort of repeater. You want to set the ASUS to `AP mode` and make sure it's connected on the LAN port, not the WAN port.

This is much easier than using 2 different subnets and NAT. :P

Comment: Oh well yes! Thanks I found it in Administration on how to change the mode to AP. That really worked for me. You are the best! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really described what it is you want to do with both these routers or why you're creating two separate LANs. But I presume that you just want the first router to act as your internet gateway and the second to act as a wireless access point.

To do that, you don't need to create two LANS. Having a NAT router behind another NAT router will cause all kinds of issues.

What you probably want to do is to have the second router to simply act as a switch with a built in access point. If that's the case, turn off the second router's DHCP server, and connect one of its **LAN** ports (yes,LAN!) to a **LAN** port of the main gateway. Since LAN ports are normally switched, that would allow clients connected to the second router to receive an IP from the **first router's** DHCP server. This way you'll have a single 192.168.1.0/24 LAN with a single gateway to the Internet.

Comment: I tried like you suggested earlier but the issue with that is this router says that it is not connected to internet since it doesn't have any WAN ip and as a result the applications which come with this router don't work. It is even unable to update its own time.